# Activate button to get to next page while scraping (Python, BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, html, button, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to build a dataset of Fifa 2020 players. I'm just getting into web scraping with Python BeatifulSoup.
So I wanted to scrape from this website: https://sofifa.com/?r=200061&set=true&showCol%5B%5D=ae&showCol%5B%5D=oa&showCol%5B%5D=pt&showCol%5B%5D=vl&showCol%5B%5D=hi&showCol%5B%5D=wi&showCol%5B%5D=pf&showCol%5B%5D=bo&showCol%5B%5D=pi
So far, I'm able to get the content I want. But I have the issue that the website shows the first 60 players and then there is a "next" button and I don't know how to activate it to continue scraping on the next page.
I want to get the data of all the players.

This is what I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
 
# create dataframe to store data
column_names = ["Name", "Age", "Overall Rating", "Potential", "Team", "Contract expiry", "Height", "Weight", "Strong foot", "Value"] 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)


headers = {'User-Agent': 
           'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

page = "https://sofifa.com/?r=200054&set=true&showCol%5B%5D=ae&showCol%5B%5D=oa&showCol%5B%5D=pt&showCol%5B%5D=vl&showCol%5B%5D=hi&showCol%5B%5D=wi&showCol%5B%5D=pf&showCol%5B%5D=bo"
pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=headers)
pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')

Players = pageSoup.find_all("a", {"class": "tooltip"})
Age = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "col col-ae"})
OR = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "col col-oa col-sort"})
PR = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "col col-pt"})
Team = pageSoup.find_all("div", {"class": "bp3-text-overflow-ellipsis"})
contract = pageSoup.find_all("div", {"class": "sub"})
height = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "col col-hi"})
weight = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "col col-wi"})
PF = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "col col-pf"})
Value = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "col col-vl"})


Players_List = []
Age_List = []
OR_List = []
PR_List = []
Team_List = []
contract_List = []
height_List = []
weight_List = []
PF_List = []
Value_List = []

j = 1

for i in range(0,60):
    Players_List.append(Players[i].text)
    Age_List.append(Age[i].text)
    OR_List.append(OR[i].text)
    PR_List.append(PR[i].text)
    Team_List.append(Team[i+j].text)
    contract_List.append(contract[i].text)
    height_List.append(height[i].text)
    weight_List.append(weight[i].text)
    PF_List.append(PF[i].text)
    Value_List.append(Value[i].text)
    j=j+1
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":Players_List, "Age": Age_List, "Overall Rating":OR_List, "Potential":PR_List, "Team":Team_List, "Contract expiry":contract_List, "Height":height_List,"Weight":weight_List, "Strong foot":PF_List, "Value":Value_List})
```

Hope someone can help me here

Comment: I would suggest you one of this two approaches:

a. Using a library like Selenium, which permits you simulate different user inputs.
b. If you check the requests that are making to the server (or even the URL), at the end there is a parametter called offset. That is used in order to know what players to show. So you can just be incrementing it in order to get the players you want.

Comment: You can't do that with `BeautifulSoup`. It can just scrape pages. It can't click on a button or something else... That is a part of automation. And for that you need to use `selenium`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed there's an `offset` at the end of the link, so you can edit your code like this without the need to use `selenium`:

```
number_of_pages = 10
page = "https://sofifa.com/?r=200061&set=true&showCol[]=ae&showCol[]=oa&showCol[]=pt&showCol[]=vl&showCol[]=hi&showCol[]=wi&showCol[]=pf&showCol[]=bo&showCol[]=pi&offset="
for num_page in range(0, 10):
    pageTree = requests.get(page+str(num_page*60), headers=headers)
    """
        Rest of the code
    """
```

Comment: I see. I was able to make it work, with the information you provided. Thank you very much.

Comment: I was just wondering if you have any idea how to collect the full name of the players, Right now I get "L. Messi" insteaf of "Lionel Messi". This is the html structure:

Comment: <a class="tooltip" href="/player/158023/lionel-messi/200061/" data-tooltip="Lionel Messi">                                                                                                                                       ::before

Comment: <div class="bp3-text-overflow-ellipsis">                                                                         <img title="Argentina" alt src="https://cdn.sofifa.com/flags/ar.png" data-src="https://cdn.sofifa.com/flags/ar.png" data-srcset="https://cdn.sofifa.com/flags/ar@2x.png 2x, https://cdn.sofifa.com/flags/ar@3x.png 3x" class="flag loaded" srcset="https://cdn.sofifa.com/flags/ar@2x.png 2x, https://cdn.sofifa.com/flags/ar@3x.png 3x" data-was-processed="true">                                                                               "L.Messi"

Comment: When you get the element "a", extract from it the info inside "data-tooltip".

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't seem to understand how to get that information.

Comment: Players[0] will output me: <a class="tooltip" data-tooltip="Lionel Messi" href="/player/158023/lionel-messi/200061/"><div class="bp3-text-overflow-ellipsis"><img alt="" class="flag" data-src="https://cdn.sofifa.com/flags/ar.png" data-srcset="https://cdn.sofifa.com/flags/ar@2x.png 2x, https://cdn.sofifa.com/flags/ar@3x.png 3x" src="" title="Argentina"/> L. Messi</div></a>

Comment: Players[0].text will give me "L. Messi" only

Comment: try Players[0].get("data-tooltip")

Comment: I gotta work on my knowledge. Jesus. Thank you so much!.